# UWP: WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync not working for dropbox?

Tags: uwp, oauth, dropbox

The method `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync` from the `Windows.Security.Authentication.Web` namespace seems to work for Google, but not for Dropbox. For Dropbox, it shows "Can't connect to the service".

Fastest way to reproduce (for UWP and Xamarin.UWP):

Use
`var requestUri = new Uri("https://dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?dummyQueryString");` in a call with

`var response = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, requestUri, new Uri("dummycallbackUri:/"));`

This results in:

[image: Can't connect so the service]

Calling it with

`var requestUri = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?dummyQueryString");`

results in Google-content being displayed (a 400 Bad Request, but that is as expected with a dummy query string).

I tested another random requestUri "https://stackoverflow.com/" that has nothing to do with OAuth, I get:

[image: Sorry, we no longer support Internet Explorer]

This last example may provide some information on how the `WebAuthenticationBroker` works... is it really using an old browser while I'm using the latest version of Mozilla FireFox as my default browser?

How can I use `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync` for Dropbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to why it's showing an error instead of the page, but Dropbox doesn't officially support processing the OAuth app authorization flow in a web view like this ([per docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize)), so you should send this through the system browser instead anyway.

These web views sometimes do use old browser engines instead of whatever you have installed as your system browser, so they are more prone to compatibility issues like that.

Comment: Thanks for connecting the dots! I never suspected that the WebAuthenticationBroker would use a "web view". I knew that web views are not supported, but I thought of them as something app developers use - this class seems closer to the operating system and out of scope for that restriction. Currently, [Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticator invokes this method](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/7218ab88f7fbe00ec3379bd54e6c0ce35ffc0c22/Xamarin.Essentials/WebAuthenticator/WebAuthenticator.uwp.cs#L17) and I never suspected it would be unsupported in any way.

Answer (score 0):

good luck. i know your pain. this is a heinou tangle
that i just sorted out.
few things:

yes use the AuthenticateAsync(starturi);
no dont use the overload AuthenticateAsync(starturi, callbackuri);
overload if you are a public client (desktop app not using a client cert). it wont work. you only need to provide the reply url in the query string. i cant find now, buti learned in a weird place, i think a token descriptor table in a microsoft learn doc that, public clients use the sso flow, and that you cant use that second reply url param in authasync for sso. but you d still need to add the reply url as a query arg on you start uri. you can construct the start uri bylooking here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code

for 3p account providers, you need to set it up in the appx manifext under declaration>webaccountprovider.
[image]

the reply url needs to be "real." if you want to use localhost, thats a whole other uwp shit show. localhost needs to be registered as a reply url with the app registration. its insecure so dont do if ur appid is already GA or in prod. also, even if you do register it, you also still needs to move mountins to allow uwp to app to not block. you need to add it to a loopback exemption by ding this

cmd window

```
> Get-AppxPackage <your app name>
Name              : 
...
PackageFamilyName : someprefix.someprefix.CamelCaseName_alplhanumwekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId       : alplhanumwekyb3d8bbwe
...
Status            : Ok
  
> CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n=CamelCaseName_alplhanumwekyb3d8bbwe
OK.
> CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -s
List Loopback Exempted AppContainers

[1] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Name: AppContainer NOT FOUND
    SID:  S-1-15-2-1...

[2] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Name: someprefix.CamelCaseName_alplhanumwekyb3d8bbwe
    SID:  S-1-15-2-...<legit SID>
```